# Canon LBP6030 is not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: printing

I am a new user of Ubuntu and I have a Canon printer(LBP6030). I have tried several methods to install the printer. But I can not print anyhow. Is there anyone who can give me a workable solution?
Thanks

Comment: How have you attached the printer to the computer, USB or wireless? If wireless, did you login with the digits of the serial number? What have you tried, CUPS (port 631 off your machine)? What are you trying to print and with what program? (some apps, like evince, will simply not print a postscript file.) More suggestions tomorrow, I have a 6030w to attach myself.

Comment: See question 725130, basically download the latest Linux driver (5.0) from the Canon site, read the Documents/README and User manual from the unpacked driver, and run the install.sh. pick the LPD offering when you add a settings/printer/add (give the wireless address you set up from attaching the printer via USB to a Windows machine (get the Windows driver) and running the network tool). All assumes CUPS is running, but it is by default.